# NSIS: Making Embedded ListView with CheckBoxes transparent

Tags: nsis

I have created a ListView with checkboxes using the embeddedLists.dll plugin. I need to make the background of the HeadingText transparent for this project.

I used WinSpy++ to get the handle_Id and tried this snippet, but it did not work.

```
FindWindow $0 "#32770" "" $HWNDPARENT
GetDlgItem $0 $0 1211
SetCtlColors $0 "FFFFFF" "transparent"
```

Any pointers/help is very much appreciated.

Adding screenshot for clarity.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ym708.png)

Comment: Are you talking about "Select the services to be installed" or "Select the services"? Posting the page creation code would also be helpful.

Comment: "Select the services to be installed" area.

The ini file:
<code>
[Settings]
Type=ListView
Caption=Services
HeadingText=Select the Services to be installed.
GroupText=Select the Services
CheckBoxes=1
ColumnHeader=0
NoItemSelection=1
ViewListOnly=0
ToggleNextButton=1

[Item 1]
Text=Service Manager One

[Item 2]
Text=Service Manager two

[Item 3]
Text=Service Manager three
<code>

Comment: I understand which items you have, I asked you for your real source code so I can actually compile instead of wasting time trying to recreate your page on my own...

Answer (score 0):

Is your installer based on UMUI skin? Some 3rd party plug-ins may have issues with transparency and so on.

Anyway I noticed you use NSIS 2.46 which is pretty old, try to run the example in new NSIS 3 and new UMUI which has many fixes and improvements.

Little self promo: I have developed plug-in for NSIS similar to UMUI called **Graphical Installer**: [image: Graphical Installer example]

Feel free to try it: [Graphical Installer website](http://graphical-installer.com) (Trial)